# Convert int to binary in JES?

Tags: python, type-conversion, jython, jes

I'm trying to convert an `int` to a binary string. This would be super easy with the `bin()` function, but this is not available in JES, which uses `Jython 2.5.2`.

I tried using this:

```python
def convertToBinary(n):
   string = ''
   if n > 1:
     convertToBinary(n//2)
   string = string  + str(n%2)
   print string

dec = 34
convertToBinary(dec)
print()
```

but `str()` is not converting it. I try removing `str`, thinking somehow `n % 2` is already a string, but nope.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by “str() is not converting it” – do you get an error, or an unexpected result?

Comment: when str() is not there, it can't concatenate a string and an int. When it is there it says there is an inappropriate argument.

Comment: What’s the full text of the “inappropriate argument” error?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a ternary operation.

```python
def convertToBinary(n):
    s = ""
    if n > 1:
        convertToBinary(n // 2)
    s = s + ("0" if n % 2 == 0 else "1")
    print s
```

Or, you can use the Java way of converting integers into a string.

```python
import java.lang

def convertToBinary(n):
    s = ""
    if n > 1:
        convertToBinary(n // 2)
    s = s + java.lang.String.valueOf(n % 2)
    print s
```